# Exercise for shoulders strength with no special equipment

Tags: exercise, strength, shoulders, home-exercise, bodyweight-exercises

I'm traveling to a long period and neither able to attend a gym on a regular basis, nor to have equipment like dumbbells. I'm keen to do full-body workouts, but still can't find an exercise for shoulders. Can you recommend one?

My options at the moment:

- handstand push-ups. I'm not very good at hand-standing now (even against the wall), but I'm practicing. Also it seems that this exercise has limited amplitude, because you need to do something with your head hitting the floor :)
- pull-ups. Rarely an option because it's really hard to find a pull-up bar in most places I live.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago when I was looking to make my routine a bit more well rounded.

At the moment I am doing:

- [Pike Press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BWPikePress.html), depending on how you do them, they may have more focus on your chest than on your back. Compare them with [Pike Push Ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralClavicular/BWPikePushup.html). The closer your feet are to your hands the more focus you get on your shoulders, so both exercises are often mixed up or simply just called *Pike Push Ups*. (as in the videos below)
- [Side Bridges](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Obliques/BWSideBridge.html) and Bridges are mainly focused on the abs and the core in general but use a lot of shoulder muscles for control.

When I look for new exercises I often check out Youtube and search for the muscle group I want to train and checkout the exercises on other sites (like exrx) afterwards.

Some videos I recently bookmarked:
[Best Bodyweight Shoulder Exercise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPU9rvvBfdw) - shows that you can do pike push ups even with a cat in the way.
[4 Killer Shoulder Exercises *Home Workout Routine*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=ZlMUT2SqJj0) - silly music, but good explanations.
[10 Shoulders Exercises (body weight)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JH2FmRXxKEo) - just some dude doing exercises, no further explanation given.

Be careful with videos though, you never know if they are done with good form, so check at least two or three other resources before attempting an exercise. As always: if it hurts or feels strange, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Informaficker and his two exercises. The plank is also a very good exercise to work the stabilizers in the shoulders. I also saw this one where, while in the plank position, you alternate the hands coming up with a punch. After about 10 of those, you will start to feel the burn.